# How do I make circles within a larger circle, and text within the center of all the circles, in CSS?

Tags: html, css, text, geometry, shapes

How do I make circles with positions relative to the other inner circles within a larger circle, and text within the center of all the circles, in CSS?

I'm looking to produce something similar to this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/viMES.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this

CSS

```
    .outer_circle {
    height:400px;
    line-height:400px;
    width:400px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:#000000;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    }

.outer_circle p {
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    color:#ffffff;
    }

.circle {
    background-color:#aeaeae;
    border-radius:50%;
    height:40px;
    line-height:20px;
    width:40px;
    position:absolute;
    margin:10px;
    }

.circle p {
    font-size:10px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    color:#000000;
    }
```

html

```
    <div class="outer_circle" >
<div class="circle" style="top:10px;left:150px"><p>Text</p></div>
<div class="circle" style="top:70px;left:260px"><p>Text</p></div>
<div class="circle" style="top:150px;left:320px"><p>Text</p></div>
<div class="circle" style="top:250px;left:260px"><p>Text</p></div>
<div class="circle" style="bottom:70px;left:150px"><p>Text </p></div>


<p> Text Text   Text Text   Text Text Text Text </p>
```

Adjust the height, width etc according you needs.
Hope this helps